# Subset data in ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I have the following data and am trying to summarize it so that I have the id, tone, and count of tone for each name. However, I also want to have the tone rate (tone_cnt / sum of id  for that name). Unfortunately, I've messed around with this and have had little luck.

```
    df = data.frame(name=c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b"),
                    id = c(35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36),
                    tone=c(0,1,1,2,2,3,2,1,2,2,2))
    df
    sum = ddply(df, .(name, id, tone), summarise, 
Tone_Cnt=length(tone), Tone_Rate=Tone_Cnt/sum(Tone_Cnt))
    sum
```

have messed around with length(), sum(), sum(length()) and nothing seems to get the trick done. Currently, it just spits out 1 for everyone.

Here's how it should look like:

```
> sum
  name id tone Tone_Cnt Tone_Rate
1    a 35    0        1        1 / (1+2)
2    a 35    1        2        2 / (1+2) 
3    a 36    2        2        2 / (2)
4    b 35    1        1        1 / (1+1+1)
5    b 35    2        1        1 / (1+1+1)
6    b 35    3        1        1 / (1+1+1)
7    b 36    2        3        3 / (3)
```

It's basically the tone count divided by the sum of total count for (name, id, tone)

Comment: Within each subset, `Tone_Cnt` only contains one value, and you're dividing that value by itself, which of course just gives you 1. It looks like you want to subset once by `name`, `id`, and `tone` to get `Tone_Cnt`, then again by something else to get `Tone_Rate`. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding your description of the desired output though.

Comment: Would be nice to see what the expected output looked like. Is this a nudge into the right direction? `ftable(id ~ name + tone, data = df)`

Comment: Perhaps if you described more of what you are trying to do, then we could help more.  There are some seeming inconsistencies in the description, and it would help if you manually calculated what you want to see in each column and then added that to the description.